# Converting a huge document frequency dict into pd.DataFrame makes my Linux machine freeze

Tags: python, pandas, linux, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a document-term counts nested dict in Python into `pd.DataFrame` using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` method. The dict looks like:

```py
my_dict = {"id1": Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}), "id2": Counter({'a': 4, 'd': 9, 'e': 2})}
```

The resulting DataFrame must have each doc_id as an index and each unique term in dicts as a column.

So I've decided to use:

```py
my_dict = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient="index")
```

However, the dict is huge (over 80000 indices and 500000 distinct terms), so my Linux machine freezes - I'm forced to reboot it.

Is there other way to convert the dict into Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: if it's ASCII you can save a TON of memory by switching to a 128 character array instead of saving it as dictionaries. In terms of speed or your machine freezing, what's the actual error? it could just be taking its time when processing the dictionary

Comment: I cannot do like this, because I need to extract the whole words from the documents and then store documents as N-dimensional vectors, where N is the vocabulary of the whole collection.

Comment: You would need [160 GB](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=80000*500000*4+bytes) of memory to represent this - you might have more luck using either scipy.sparse or [Pandas sparse dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/sparse.html).

Comment: Hard to say what's happening exactly, at a guess you're running out of RAM and have disabled the OOM-killer if pandas manages to freeze your machine. Watch the output of `top` for a bit while it's running. It's quite possible that the "freeze" is actually due to intense swapping (let's say you made a swap-partition/-file that's roughly the same size as your RAM) ... how much RAM does the box have, what peak values of usage do you see during your run?

Comment: Out of curiosity: how did that dict make it into the program, if it's indeed that large?

Comment: I have parse document files and tokenized them into terms and also computed their frequencies in each document.

Comment: your data seams big, try to use dask instead, it should work. And you could convert some of or columns to categorical and if needed transform to pandas df, but ddf might suffice your needs.